# How to properly use casper.each in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm writing a small script to query some ads on an e-commerce website. My code is like this

```
    var keywords = ['fender', 'yamaha'];
    var casper = require('casper').create(),
        url = 'http://www.somecommercesite.com';

    casper.start(url, function () {
        casper.each(keywords, function (self, word) {
            casper.echo("Getting entries for keyword " + word + "..");

            casper.fill('form#frmsearch', {
                'q': word
            }, true);

            casper.then(function () {
                casper.echo("KEYWORD SHOULD BE: " + word);

                var actualKeyword = casper.evaluate(function() {
                    return "ACTUAL KEYWORD: " + document.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerText;
                });
                casper.echo(actualKeyword);

                var result = casper.evaluate(function () {
                    var entry = document.getElementsByClassName("listing")[0];
                    return entry.innerText;
                });
                casper.echo(result);
            });
        });
    });

    casper.run();
```

However, I got incorrect results. The output was

```
Getting entries for keyword fender..    
Getting entries for keyword yamaha..    
KEYWORD SHOULD BE: fender    
ACTUAL KEYWORD: fender    
// entries for fender

KEYWORD SHOULD BE: yamaha   
ACTUAL KEYWORD: fender    
// entries for fender
```

So, I got fender entries twice and never got yamahas. What's wrong with those code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. I need to surround casper.fill() with casper.then().